# How to disable the bash "bell" on ConsoleZ?

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, console2, bell

I am using ConsoleZ to work on multiple Cygwin bash terminals. I use the <kbd>Teb</kbd> extensively for path completion. But by default, the "bell" sound is heard whenever the completion is not unique. This became annoying, so I looked for a way to disable that beep.

When using Cygwin's terminal directly, I can disable that sound via the settings dialog. However, I cannot locate such setting in ConsoleZ.

How can I disable the bell beep in ConsoleZ (or Console2)?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is a bash readline feature. One needs to set the `bell-style` variable in `.inputrc` as follows:

```
set bell-style none
```

and start a new terminal instance for this to take effect.